# Detect clicks inside google.maps.InfoWindow ({ content: contentString });

Tags: javascript, events, click, maps

Is it possible to detect clicks inside of the infowindow in Google Maps?

```
var contentString = '<div id="content"><a href='#' data-id='click'>test</a></div>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: contentString
});
```

Comment: I edited your question so it did not get closed.

Comment: Your code has invalid string variables, the `href` and the `data-id` attributes should be delimited with `"` to avoid breaking your initial `contentString = '<div  ...`

Comment: thanks, I fixed    var contentString = '<div id="content"><a href="#" data-id="click">test</a></div>';

Answer (score 0):

How about to:

- attach `click` handler to body
- utilize [`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) to determine whether info window node is clicked or not

For example:

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var anchor = document.querySelector('a[data-id="click"]');
    if (anchor && anchor.contains(event.target)) {
       console.log("Info window is clicked..");
    } 
});
```

[**Demo**](https://codepen.io/vgrem/pen/vQdOgP)

Comment: Hi Vadim Gremyachev, document.body.addEventListener does not work inside iframe